# What Makes a Number Memorable mathematically ? (Suggestions)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, arithmetic, reverse-math

I'm not a mathematician but I love Maths . I have a presentation about a telecom company my question is a little bit long so I want you to to suggest methods on what makes a phone number memorable and 1) I want mathematical methods that will allow me to find all memorable numbers in a certain method and also 2) normal methods that you can find by observation and 3 ) can you help me convert normal methods into mathematical one for 10 digits numbers that have 06 prefix + 8 digits like 06X(1)X(2)X(3)X(4)X(5)X(6)X(7)X(8) and I already have many methods that i have found and I want you to help me with more ideas and suggestions and here is some methods :

1/ Single repeats : 06 1111 2222

2/ Repeated pairs : 06 22 33 44 55

3 / Double repeats ascending : 06 6464 9292

4 / Consecutive runs descending : 06 1234 5678

5 / Step up digits : 06 12 32 52 72

6 / Step down digits : 06 90 80 70 60

7 / Mirrored digits : 06 1221 8998

8 / Double repeats : 06 6464 9292

9 / Repeated prifixes : 06 9800 9856

10 / keypad (in one line) : 06 2580 159 9

11 / Years : 06 1986 2018

12 / 06 XX 06 XX 06 while we can apply previous methos with X and X or XX and XX

13 / Last repeats : 06 25 59 97 78

14 / mixing methods : like (3,4) : 06 6464 5678

Now mathematical methods that are simular to some of the previous methods :

1 / Arithmetic sequences :

06X(1)X(2)X(3)X(4)X(5)X(6)X(7)X(8) Ex : 06 0123 4567

06U(1)U(2)U(3)U(4) EX : 06 12 14 16 18

06Z(1)Z(2) EX : 06 5000 5001

and others

2 / geometric sequences :

06U(1)U(2)U(3)U(4) ex : 06 02 04 08 16

06Z(1)Z(2) ex : 06 1000 2000

06X(1)X(2)X(3)X(4)X(5)X(6) ex : 06 1 2 4 8 16 32

and others

3 / OTHER MATHEMATICAL METHODS ?

So Can please help me convert previous normal methods into mathematical one and other methods that you know or you use to remember numbers ?

Comment: Quick Tip Make sure you use Mathjax, it makes it easier to read and is more proper.

Comment: "I want mathematical methods that will allow me to find all memorable numbers in a certain method"  Why  would you think there are *any*.

Comment: @fleablood because a lot of numbers have like a pattern that's why i want like to find the general blueprint to get all simular numbers just using like c or java and computer will give all simular numbers